# what's the difference between these two callback in react-redux?

Tags: reactjs, promise, redux, react-redux

I am learning react-redux with the Udemy course. Meet this code,

```
 export function createPost(value, callback){
       const request = axios.post(url, value).then(() => callback());
    }
```

why not just put the callback like this

```
const request = axios.post(url, value).then(callback);
```

---

EDIT

in the video they call this function like this

```
this.props.createPost(value, () => this.props.history.push('/'));
```

2.

Since they called by `this.props.createPost(value, () => this.props.history.push('/'));`

**I thought the callback is already a function** `() => this.props.history.push('/')` ;

so why they wraped the callback again in the definition `createPost` by `Promise.then(() => callback())`

In my opinion just put the callback like `Promise.then(callback)` is ok.

Am I wrong?

Comment: this will also work: `axios.post(url, value).then(callback);` but in this case you can't pass some value to that function but in 1st case you can: `const request = axios.post(url, value).then(() => callback('success'));`

Answer (score 1):

if you take a closer look your function call takes one param, which means if you append parenthesis at the end it will be IMMEDIATELY called:

```
this.props.history.push('/')
```

if you try to do:

```
this.props.createPost(value, this.props.history.push('/')); // without the () =>
```

the function `history.push` will be called immediately, what you are doing is context binding, by creating a lambda function you are delaying the execution and also adding a constant param `'/'`.

Another way to achieve this:

```
this.props.createPost(value, this.props.history.push.bind(null, '/')
```

Read [Bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

If your function did not take any params then you could do as you wish (without the parenthesis ofc)

```
this.props.createPost(value, this.props.anotherFunction) // anotherFunction does not take any params, and does can be passed as is
```

Comment: but in the EDIT , by my understanding, they called function createPost already with a composed function `this.props.createPost(value, () => this.props.history.push('/'))`  , why in the function definition`Promise.then(() => callback())` again ?

Comment: any idea about my comments? I

Comment: as I said: if you don't wrap the callback function inside a lambda function it will me immediately executed, what you want is delayed execution after the promise has returned AND bind the parameter '/' to the function call

Comment: But I thought that the callback is already wrap itself by `() => this.props.history.push('/')` is it necessary to wrap it again by `() => callback()`?

Comment: if you create the call back as:

`const callback = () => this.props.history.push('/')` and then do `this.props.createPost(value, callback);` you are doing the exact same thing, you are just moving the definition outside the declaration of the outer function.